# deploy iphone app in windows7

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app that I built in html and javascript that i would like to test on an iphone.  I have a apple developers license.  How can I get it from my windows computer to an iphone?

Comment: I think you NEED a mac to even run any software from your computer to your phone. I could be wrong though... anyone?

Comment: How is it packaged?  (That is, if it's nothing but HTML and Javascript, it's a web site rather than an "app".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact there is a way. Please take a look at [this](http://support.brightcove.com/en/app-cloud/docs/step-step-guide-publishing-apple-app-store-using-windows) step-by-step guide for that process.And also you can take a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165644/is-there-a-way-to-publish-ios-app-from-windows-linux) question on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a Mac... no other way around this :(

Comment: Hackintosh (virtual mac os on your pc) is an other way :) Ofcourse its bad and wrong and never do it! :P

Answer (score 0):

To build anything development wise for iPhone or iOS in general, must have a Mac.

However, if it is something you need to test that is html and js like you mentioned. Have a look at this plug in for google chrome.

I used this before to develop for multi platform web app. It also simulates accelerometer and gps too.

[google plug in Ripple Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)